# How to get transition circle and tooltip on line chart dynamically

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to have tooltip and small circle on the line graph whenever user mouses over on line chart. this is my code for line chart.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

div.circle{
  border-radius: 50%;        
  width: 30px;                  
  height: 30px;                 
}
</style>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

data = [

  {date: 1,temp:10},{date: 2,temp:40},{date: 3,temp:90},
  {date: 4,temp:30},{date: 5,temp:20},{date: 6,temp:10}
];

  var margin = {top: 20,left: 30, bottom: 30,right: 40},
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
      width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right;

  var x = d3.time.scale()
            .range([0,width]);

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height,0]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
              .scale(x)
              .orient("bottom");

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
              .scale(y)
              .orient("left");

  var chart = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                          .attr("width",width + margin.left + margin.right)
                          .attr("height",height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                          .append("g")
                          .attr("transform","translate("+margin.left+","+margin.top+")");

  var line = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d){return x(d.date);})
                .y(function(d){return y(d.temp);})
                .interpolate("linear");

    x.domain(d3.extent(data,function(d){return d.date}));
    y.domain([d3.min(data,function(d){return d.temp}),d3.max(data,function(d){return d.temp})]);

    chart.append("g")
          .attr("class","x axis")
          .attr("transform","translate(0,"+height+")")
          .call(xAxis);
    chart.append("g")
          .attr("class","y axis")
          .call(yAxis);
    chart.append("path")
          .attr("class", "line")
          .attr("d",line(data))
          .attr("stroke","red")
          .attr("stroke-width",2)
          .attr("fill","none")
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I get transition circle and tooltip dynamically on line chart? I tried to capture mouse's x and y co ordinate and display circle in that co-ordinates but doesn't looks good. [check my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20761091/mouseover-on-line-doesnt-give-circle-in-d3-js)

Answer (score 5):

First solution **[here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3902569)**

Or you need to bind mouseover like

```
.on("mouseover", function() {
    console.log({"x": d3.event.x, "y": d3.event.y});
});
```

that will give you a current position display circle on this position with tooltip
more reference [here](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/line.html)

also
you can pre-render circle and on mouseover move it to current position and on mouseout or ser some timeout to hide it